find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
enter image description here
This is the error I am getting while npm install.
I have downloaded visual studio 2022 and done all the environment set up. Also installed python still getting the same issue.
Please help in resolving this issue.
